# Mocking spring controller validator

Tags: spring, junit, jmock

I want to unit test this Spring controller method:

```
@Autowired
private MyValidator validator;

public String register(
    HttpServletRequest request, 
    ModelMap model, 
    Principal principal,
    @PathVariable Plain plain, 
    RedirectAttributes ratts,
    @ModelAttribute @Valid PlainMoreObject pmo, 
    BindingResult result) 
{

    validator.validate(pmo, result);
```

I'm using JMock. How do I mock the validator in order to test controller by calling

```
  controller.register(....) ?
```

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789529/inject-a-mockups-to-a-bean-that-has-autowired-annotations

Answer (score 1):

There is a helper class in Spring called ReflectionTestUtils ([link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html)) you can use to inject mocked beans to fields.

```
@Mock MyValidator validatorMock;
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controller, "validator", validatorMock);
controller.register(...);
```